# how to organize the JSON object to keys and values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I get **JOSN** in this format from an API. I get column and row in a separate key. is is possible to join the column and row into a *single object*.

```
{
    "datasource": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "columns": [
        "Last Activity Date-Time",
        "Name",
        "City",
        "Age",
        "Gender",
        "Initial Inquiry Date",
        "Status",
        "Anticipated_Move-in",
        "LastContacted",
        "NextStep",
        "Lead Score"
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            "2019-03-07T12:56:00",
            "Harold Glucks",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "03/05/2019",
            "LOST (No Potential for Move-In)",
            "",
            "03/07/2019",
            "Email                        ",
            "100"
        ],
        [
            "2018-05-14T10:23:00",
            "Lea Deitch",
            "",
            "",
            "Female",
            "05/17/2017",
            "LOST (No Potential for Move-In)",
            "",
            "05/14/2018",
            "Phone Call - Lead",
            "100"
        ],
        [
            "2019-02-08T13:19:00",
            "Donna Snoderly",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "08/22/2018",
            "WARM (Move-In Likely in 30-60 Days)",
            "",
            "02/08/2019",
            "Email                        ",
            "100"
        ]
    ],
    "numRows": 3,
    "numColumns": 11,
    "fromcache": true
}
```

i tried adding the column to an array and row to another array. merging this array didn't work what i expected.
i want to organize the object to this format, is this possible?

```
[
    { 
        Last Activity Date-Time : "2019-03-07T12:56:00",
        Name: "Harold Glucks",
        City: "",
        Age: "",
        Gender: "",
        Initial Inquiry Date: "03/05/2019",
        Status: "LOST (No Potential for Move-In)",
        Anticipated_Move-in: "",
        LastContacted: "03/07/2019",
        NextStep: "Email",
        Lead Score: "100"
    },
    {
        Last Activity Date-Time : "2019-03-07T12:56:00",
        Name: "Harold Glucks",
        City: "",
        Age: "",
        Gender: "",
        Initial Inquiry Date: "03/05/2019",
        Status: "LOST (No Potential for Move-In)",
        Anticipated_Move-in: "",
        LastContacted: "03/07/2019",
        NextStep: "Email",
        Lead Score: "100"
    },
    {
        Last Activity Date-Time : "2019-03-07T12:56:00",
        Name: "Harold Glucks",
        City: "",
        Age: "",
        Gender: "",
        Initial Inquiry Date: "03/05/2019",
        Status: "LOST (No Potential for Move-In)",
        Anticipated_Move-in: "",
        LastContacted: "03/07/2019",
        NextStep: "Email",
        Lead Score: "100"
    }
]
```

Comment: what does actually not work?

Comment: Loop over the the columns array and a single row array. columns[0] is the key for rows[0][0] and rows[1][0] ... rows[x][0], columns[1] is the key for rows[0][1] ... rows[x][1]. So you just use the index of the loop. If you want to be less loopy, create one obejct from the columns first, then only loop the rows to clone the object and fill it the correct values from the current row. But first thing should be to check the API docs to see if you can't get the API to return your requested format to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the rows and map the columns as keys and take objects.

```js
var data = { datasource: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", columns: ["Last Activity Date-Time", "Name", "City", "Age", "Gender", "Initial Inquiry Date", "Status", "Anticipated_Move-in", "LastContacted", "NextStep", "Lead Score"], rows: [["2019-03-07T12:56:00", "Harold Glucks", "", "", "", "03/05/2019", "LOST (No Potential for Move-In)", "", "03/07/2019", "Email", "100"], ["2018-05-14T10:23:00", "Lea Deitch", "", "", "Female", "05/17/2017", "LOST (No Potential for Move-In)", "", "05/14/2018", "Phone Call - Lead", "100"], ["2019-02-08T13:19:00", "Donna Snoderly", "", "", "", "08/22/2018", "WARM (Move-In Likely in 30-60 Days)", "", "02/08/2019", "Email", "100"]], numRows: 3, numColumns: 11, fromcache: true }
    result = data.rows.map(a => Object.assign(...data.columns.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: a[i] }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(json);

const merged = _.map(obj.rows, (r, i) => {
  return _.zipObject(obj.columns, r);
});
```